# Layout before in different parent node

Tags: magento-1.7, layout

This is loading gtm.checkout.success *after* google.tags.head on the checkout success page. I need it to load *before*. I added the before= attribute but it doesn't work. I assume it's because they have different parent nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- Need this on all pages -->
            <block type="core/template" name="google.tags.head" template="gtm/google-tags-head.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="head">
            <!-- Need this on checkout success page BEFORE google.tags.head -->
            <block type="core/template" name="gtm.checkout.success" before="google.tags.head" template="gtm/gtm-checkout-success.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>

</layout>
```

So, question is how can I accomplish this? I tried removing google.tags.head and re-adding it but it doesn't show up at all this way...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <block type="core/template" name="google.tags.head" template="gtm/google-tags-head.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <reference name="head">
            <remove name="google.tags.head"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="gtm.checkout.success" template="gtm/gtm-checkout-success.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="google.tags.head" template="gtm/google-tags-head.phtml" after="gtm.checkout.success" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_success>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your blocks not sorting is not because they are in different parent nodes but because they are in `head` tag.

Magento will not sort blocks added in `head` tag, If you add `content` as reference name, the blocks will display in right order.

If its not required to add blocks in `head` then you can add it inside `content` and your blocks will display in correct order.

Refer to Alan Storm's Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486919/1409718) for more details

Comment: I tested this and right you are. That's odd though. So, there's no way to order elements in the head? Why would they let you order elements in content but not head?